# DB::beginTransaction showing "error:There is no active transaction" while creating tenant and domain in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, multi-tenant, laravel-10

I'm working with Tenancy for Laravel and creating a new tenant. Now I want to implement transactions, but when I do it I get this error:

```
There is no active transaction
```

The code is:

```
    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        $tenant = $tenant->create($request->data);
        $tenant->domains()->create(['domain' => $request->domain.config('constants.domain_suffix')]);
        

        DB::commit();
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors(__($e->getMessage()))->withInput();
    }
```

I also tried this code :

```
    DB::transaction(function () use ($request, &$tenant) {
        $tenant->create($request->data);
        $tenant->domains()->create(['domain' => $request->domain.config('constants.domain_suffix')]);
    });
```

This error showing while create tenant not for update case.

So, I don`t know if the function beginTransaction is wrong or something.

Comment: There are some MySQL statements that bypass a Transaction, like `CREATE TABLE ...`, but at a glance, this code _should_ be safe. Is there something happening behind the scenes in `$tenant->create()` or `$tenant->domains()->create()` maybe?

Comment: Cannot claim to have used this but DDL commands have a builtin Commit, so if you are running any DDL rather than just SQL your transaction will have been closed by a DDL